# Customize select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

there is data in 2 tables like below.

Table A:

```
C1|C2
------
A|1   
B|2
```

Table B:

```
C1|C4
-------
A|1
B|1
```

The output should have primary key C1 and C2 from table A and C3 from table B like below.

```
C1|C2|C4
---------
A|NULL|NULL
B|2|1
```

To achieve this, the basic query will look like below. Can any one tell me if we can put two column names using only one case statement.

```
select A.C1, 
       case when A.C2<>B.C4 then A.C2 end as "C2", 
       case when A.C2<>B.C4 then B.C4 end as "C4" 
 from A, B 
  where A.C1=B.C1;
```

In the above, to get 2nd column from both the tables, I am using same case statement twice. Is there an alternate way to achieve this output in more simplified way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  A `case` statement only returns one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select A.C1, case when A.C2<>B.C4 then A.C2 || " " || B.C4 end as "C2-C4" 
from A, B 
where A.C1=B.C1;
```

This will give you one column with both values, but if you need separate columns, then no you need to leave it as it is.